# R: GLM between treatment groups for each colony: effect plot

Tags: r, plot, glm, lme4, posthoc

I'm still learning how to use r and I have some trouble making an effect plot based on Tukey posthoc tests. I have a dataset with 3 colonies (`A`, `B` and `C`, see below). Each colony is divided into 2 treatments: `control` and `DWV`. I have to run a GLM to test wether there is a difference of life expectancy last.scan between the treatment groups for each of the colonies. I have taken 'treatment' as a fixed factor and 'colony' as a random factor.

I used the following code:

```
fit_life = lmer(last.scan~treatment + (1|colony), data = data)
Anova(fit_life, type = 3)
```

I also need the 95% confidence limits, but I am not sure if I use the correct command:

```
confint(lsmeans(fit_life, list(~treatment)), type = "response")
```

The following command gives me the results of the Tukey posthoc tests for the treatments, but I want a Tukey test that gives me the difference between treatment in each colony. How can I do that?

```
mcp = glht(fit_life, linfct = mcp(treatment = "Tukey"))
summary(mcp)
# DWV treatment significantly changes life expectancy (z = -9.734, p = < 2e-16)
```

With the results of the posthoc test, I want to make an effect plot like the one shown here, but I do not know what command to use.[image]

Here is an example of the dataset:

```
> head(data, 30)
                       RFID colony treatment last.scan
1  A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 20 01      A   Control        24
2  A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 20 0C      A   Control        21
3  A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 20 1D      A   Control        19
4  A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 20 1E      A   Control        18
5  A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 20 1F      A   Control        31
6  A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 20 21      A   Control        19
7  A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 20 2F      A   Control        18
8  A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 20 37      A   Control        16
9  A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 20 5E      A   Control        23
10 A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 20 79      A   Control        19
11 A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 20 7F      A   Control        17
12 A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 20 8C      A   Control        24
13 A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 20 92      A   Control        26
14 A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 20 95      A   Control        19
15 A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 20 98      A   Control        21
16 A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 20 B8      A   Control        21
17 A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 20 B9      A   Control        20
18 A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 20 D5      A   Control        17
19 A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 20 D9      A   Control        27
20 A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 20 E4      A   Control        26
21 A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 20 FE      A   Control        31
22 A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 3A 02      A       DWV        11
23 A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 3A 0C      A       DWV        22
24 A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 3A 0D      A       DWV        12
25 A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 3A 11      A       DWV        19
26 A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 3A 14      A       DWV        21
27 A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 3A 1D      A       DWV        24
28 A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 3A 24      A       DWV         9
29 A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 3A 2A      A       DWV        16
30 A0 01 03 C0 00 C0 3A 2C      A       DWV        23
```

Comment: I don't see your example plot. This belongs on [SO], if you can wait, we'll migrate it there.

Comment: I added the example plot. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Just do `pairs(lsmeans(...))`

Comment: @ rvl.
I do not really understand what I get if I use `pairs(lsmeans(...))`:
`> pairs(lsmeans(fit_life, list(~treatment)), type = "response")
 contrast              estimate        SE        df         t.ratio p.value
 Control - DWV 4.770355 0.4900888 831.08   9.734  <.0001`